# How to assign a tooltip at a macro button added by customize ribbon in ms excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I want to assign a tool-tip to a macro button added by customizing ribbon in options at file tab in MS Excel.

I know the userform option in vba window under insert menu allows to add tool-tip for buttons added by userform, but I want to know Can I not add tooltip for macro button added at any of the default tab in ms excel?

See the screenshot

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJBzB.png]

Comment: I don't know if this is possible (I definitely know that I don't know how to do it!).   MS have some interesting (but advanced) information on Dynamic Ribbon customisation - try here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548011(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Customizing the ribbon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850836/how-to-add-a-custom-ribbon-tab-using-vba Adding Tool-Tips to a custom ribbon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681342/add-tooltip-to-excel-add-in-custom-ribbon-ui-xml

Comment: dear @EyePeaSea, thanks for your response. i have asked one more question please help me. the link of the question is http://superuser.com/questions/982874/how-to-use-conditional-formatting-to-search-a-specific-value-in-a-range-in-ms-ex                        THANKS A LOT